# Can't figure out how to line icon up

Tags: html, css, icons

Well I have a sticky footer and on the sticky footer I have (trying to implement them) icons. I've tried getting the first icon which is the home on the far left, but nothing worked. By nothing I mean playing with the margins, padding, and float. So here's my first question. How can I have the home icon on the left. About 5px to the left. And my second is how can I take [these](http://codepen.io/idris/pen/xcEmb/) icons and line them up side to side. I've also tried a variety of things but none seemed to work. Here's my [code](http://codepen.io/idris/pen/AonHq/). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are these icons, glyphicons, gifs or sprites? Looking at your code, they appear to be fonts...

Comment: They're icon fonts. From IcoMoon @snowYetis

Comment: Do you have the font file added in your project?

Comment: It's being hosted by IcoMoon @snowYetis

Comment: I would use your browser's dev tool, inspect the icon element and mess with the css attributes. Try using a margin-right or left. I personally do not use float much because it doesn't seem to do the trick for me in most cases. Also make sure other elements aren't interfering with the icons placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the css for the home icon:

```
.icon-home{
  color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! And so I'd just do `right:10px` for example for the next icon and so fourth?

Comment: Actually, there is a better way for them! I forked your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FHElB

Comment: (Protip: If you're just getting started with code, try to stay away from libraries. Bootstap added margins and paddings to the .container element..)

Comment: Thank you soo much. I really appreciate you assistance and tip!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :) (Also, if you want them to align to the right instead, play around with position:relative/absolute and right:5px. Also, if you're using google chrome, right click on an icon and press inspect element) Good luck!